# How to ensure repeated characters are accounted for in a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm working through the exercises in a textbook and I'm asked to create a numerology program that takes a name, assigns each letter a value based on ascending order in the alphabet and returns the sum of the letters.

The code I've written works fine for any name that doesn't repeat a letter. For example if the name is 'kayla', I know the if statement will stop at the first instance of 'a'. Is there a way within its current design to catch multiple letters or does it need to sort through the letters a different way?

```
def main():

   alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxz'
   user_name = raw_input('Please enter your name ')
   value = sum = 0

   for char in alphabet:
      value = value + 1
      if char in user_name:
          sum = sum + value

   print sum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working through a textbook, and I presume don't just want the answer, here is a hint.  You are iterating (looping) over the wrong thing.  You should be looping over `user_name`, not `alphabet`.

**Update**.  If you want a nice "Pythonic" solution to your problem, this is one way:

```
user_name = raw_input('Please enter your name ')
print sum(ord(letter.upper())-64 for letter in user_name)
```

**Explanation**:

1. `ord` returns an ASCII code for a character, such as `65` for `'A'`
2. ASCII codes for A-Z are 65 through 90, in just the right order
3. Subtracting 64 gives you `1` for `A`, `2` for `B`, and so on
4. `sum` is a built-in function that does just what you would expect
5. the parameter to `sum` is an expression that evaluates to a sequence of numbers, one for each of the letters in `user_name`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I was iterating over the wrong thing. That actually helped clear up a few other examples I had been struggling with. Its really cool to see what I was trying for with 7 lines can be done in 2.

Answer (score 1):

The `in` function only verifies if an element is present in a list. You can resolve the problem in a lot of ways but I think a good approach to learn is to create a dictionary to store letter, value pairs and then iterate over the name characters to sum the values:

```
def main():
   alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxz'
   values, val = {}, 1
   for char in alphabet:
       values[char] = val
       val += 1
   print values
   user_name = raw_input('Please enter your name ')
   value = sum = 0

   for char in user_name.lower():
       sum += values[char]

   print sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Another form is using index string function to get the value of the position of the letter in the string.
Here is the example code:

```
def main():
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxz'
    user_name = raw_input('Please enter your name ')
    sum = 0

    for char in user_name.lower():
        sum += alphabet.index(char) + 1
    print sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your second example was great that is the direction I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way using list comprehension and the built-in `sum` function:

```
   alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxz'
   user_name = raw_input('Please enter your name ')
   user_name = user_name.lower().strip()
   value = sum([alphabet.index(c)+1 for c in user_name])
   print(value)
```